# Hard time understanding the same line from 2 different .Net decompilers

Tags: c#, pointers, reference, .net-4.5, decompiling

I have a hard time understanding what this code (c# .Net 4.5) i got from two different .Net decompilers does (ILSpy, dotPeek).
ILSpy:

```
int num2;
int* arg_4C_0 = ref *(&num2);
*arg_4C_0 = 79;
```

dotPeek:

```
int num2;
IntPtr num3 = (IntPtr) &num2;
int num10 = 79;
*(int*) num3 = num10;
```

What exactly do they do? I can't follow them and none of those two implementations run on visual studio 2013(.Net framework 4.5.1 available).

Notice: the code is from winform application (PE 32-bit), directly imported in visual studio with dotPeek.

Comment: declares an int variable, then a pointer to that int variable, and then sets the value of the int to 79 via the pointer.

Comment: So the result of all of this is actually num2 =79 ??

Comment: You should ask this question on https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: My question was about understanding this part of code, which is in a high-level language. A programmers answer would be better and i got one from stephen.vakil. anyway i solved my challenge!

Comment: If these decompilers are spitting out code that will not compile, it probably means they encountered IL that could not be transformed into valid C# code.  This can happen if the original code was compiled from a different language or emitted directly as IL.  In either case, you cannot trust the decompiler's output.  If you want to know what is happening here, post the IL disassembly, and we can tell you.